# Multiple Buttons Displayed botframework fb messenger

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to display multiple buttons to the user, I tried using the builder.prompts.choice method but it seems to affect my conversation logic.

```
session.send(new builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Options", "ratios|chart|more|add", {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button}));
```

I am using bot framework to connect to multiple channels and handle input/output but it does not handle my conversation logic, that is done separately by Watson. Would a hero card with no text or title, and just buttons work, because so I haven't got it working. Ideally, I would like a button click to be sent to the bot as an input text message. I am using node.js, and connecting to fb messenger. I Would prefer to not use channelData as I plan expand to other platforms

```
var hero = new builder.HeroCard(session)
  .title("title")
  .text("text")
  .buttons([
      builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "news", "news"),
      builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "news1", "news1"),
      builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "news2", "news2")
  ]);
session.send(hero);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. When you say Using choices affect your conversation logic, what is affected? What is the behavior you require or expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple other options, one is suggested actions.  The benefit to suggested actions is that once a user clicks on their response the actions disappear.  This means you do not have to worry about handing a user response by clicking on something out of turn.  You can run into this issue with a hero card for example.

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .text("Thank you for expressing interest in our premium golf shirt! What color of shirt would you like?")
    .suggestedActions(
        builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                session, [
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=green", "Green"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=blue", "Blue"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "productId=1&color=red", "Red")
                ]
            ));
session.send(msg);
```

Since you are using the facebook channel you can also use [facebook quick replys](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies).  Sorry I do not have a  node example of this, but I see there are multiple NPM libraries which will help you to use them.  Such as [facebook-quick-replies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-facebook-quick-replies) and [botbuilder-quickreplies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-quickreplies)

Comment: Thanks Jason, it wasn't exactly what I had in mind but I am using it now and functions just as well and looks good!